# Integrating PHP functions with a database

Tags: php, mysql, function

I just submitted my work and my course leader has asked me to use PHP functions to query my database. How can I do this? Is it possible to add just "function getRooms" before my queries, and return the desired result. I need thorough briefing on functions with [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL).

For example:
How will I add a function to this code:

```
<?php
    // By Kelvin
    include ("player.php");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phplogin WHERE username = '$username'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $medipack = $row['medipack'];
    if ($_POST['object'] == "Use Medipack") {
        if ($medipack != 0) {
            mysql_query("UPDATE phplogin SET score = score + 50, health = health + 50, medipack = medipack - 1
            WHERE username = '$username'");
            echo ("<P>Medipack Used!</P>");
            $RoomNumber =5;
        }
        else {
            echo ("<P>You're all out of medipacks!</P>");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: First of all you should ask him why he is asking you that.

Comment: could you edit your question and add some of the code you are using? This would help with your question

Comment: @Phill Pafford.. I have added an example. How can I ad a function to that?

Comment: Why are you developing a First Person Shooter in PHP?

Comment: Wasn't my idea. Was my team members.... I opted for Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If he's looking for a level of abstraction between the rest of your code and the code accessing the database, wrapping the database logic in functions should be on the right path:

```
function getRooms($link){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM rooms";
    $data = array();
    if($set = mysql_query($sql)){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($set)){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return empty($data)
        ? null
        : $data;
}

$db_connection = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('name', $db_connection);
$rooms = getRooms($db_connection);
```

Wrapping these functions into a class, and accessing them by methods is another step, as the instantiated object can manage its own connection, etc., but that may be a step further than necessary. Other functions (based on what I can guess) might be:

```
function getRoomById($link, $id){ }
function getRoomsByName($link, Array $names){ }
```

Comment: **@Kelvin;** Sorry, don't do homework outright; teach to fish and all that. What you need to do is extract your database logic into manageable functions. In this case, perhaps `checkItem()` to check the type of item picked up, and `changeHp()` to update the player HP. The example I've provided should serve as a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine your course leader is referring to the PHP's native MySQL functions - http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

Comment: No, I think he is talking about user-defined functions. `Is it possible to add just "function getRooms"`.

Comment: @Michiel Pater - having seen the newly added code example, I agree - please disregard my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your queries inside PHP functions. For example, like this:

```
function &getRooms(){
    $query="SELECT id,name FROM rooms";
    $result=mysql_query($query);

    $ar_out=array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $ar_out[]=$row;
    }
    return $ar_out;
}
```

This said, you really should find a tutorial or a book on how to use [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) and [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) together. There are many things to know about code organization and performance.